# Выполнить условия в Delphi при выходе из Windows

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте! Что и как нужно прописать в Delphi, чтобы при закрытии Windows программа выполняла какие-нибудь условия.

Answer (score 6):

В код на Delphi нужно добавить обработчик событий Windows `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` либо `WM_ENDSESSION`. А уже внутри обработчиков выполнить необходимые действия. [Пример](http://www.sources.ru/delphi/delphi_events.shtml).